# Mongoclient heartbeat call increasing database connections, which is not closing

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, connection

We are using Spring Boot application, which connecting to Mongo database using mongoclient java driver. Mongoclient used heartbeat call to know the primary/secondary node, all these heartbeat calls are using connection from the connection pool, but most of the time these connection remain open, which gradually increasing the database connection count to the database, when the open connection is too high database is going down.

Please let me know if any suggestions here.

Tried to set maxIdleTimeMS as 20 seconds and maxLifeTimeMS as 120 seconds, so that no connection will remain open, but still all the connections are accumulating which bringing the database down.

Comment: they should be opened since they work in background all the time

Comment: but these keep increasing and within few weeks all the available open connections are getting exhausted, which bringing the database down.

Comment: Opened connection in heartbeat should be only one for a server endpoint. Opening a new one will happen only if the previous one failed for some reason (but in this case the previous one will be closed). What you're saying seems unlikely..